# How to trigger only the inner clickable in clickable div

Tags: javascript, html, css, hyperlink

**How to trigger only the inner clickable div in a clickable div?**

If u click on the inner blue box both inner and outer onclick events getting triggered but I just want to get the blue one triggered?

```css
.outer {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: green;
  }
  
.inner {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer" onclick="alert('Hello world from outside');" role="button" tabIndex="-1">
  <div class="inner" onclick="alert('Hello world form inside');" role="button" tabIndex="-1">
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Not sure if its necessary to mention but I want to fix this issue in React   using sass.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop event propagation with inline onclick attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387736/how-to-stop-event-propagation-with-inline-onclick-attribute)

Comment: Ohh yes. You are right. Sorry.

Comment: Found a solution/description fitting your requirements. [Link to stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34725592/link-within-a-link-onclick-event-avoid-both-click-events-triggering/34725912)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `event.stopPropagation();`  This method stops the bubbling of an event to parent elements, preventing any parent event handlers from being executed.

```
 <div class="outer" onclick="alert('Hello world from outside');" role="button" tabIndex="-1">
  <div class="inner" onclick="alert('Hello world form inside');event.stopPropagation();" role="button" tabIndex="-1">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```js
function fun(msg) {
    alert(msg);
    event.stopPropagation();
}
```

```css
.outer {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: green;
  }
  
.inner {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer" onclick="fun('Hello world from outside');" role="button" tabIndex="-1">
  <div class="inner" onclick="fun('Hello world form inside');" role="button" tabIndex="-1">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
event.target
```

like this:

html

```
<div class="_div" data-div="1"><div class="_div" data-div="2"></div></div>
```

Js

```
var match = document.querySelectorAll("._div");
for(var i = 0; i <= match.lenght; i++){
  match.item(i).addEventListener('click', function(event){
    console.log("div clicked:"event.target)
    if(event.target.dataset.div == "2"){ // do something ... }
  })
}
```